# Ноутбук не даёт видео через HDMI

Tags: экран, монитор, hdmi

Хотел подключить 2-й монитор к ноутбуку ASUS TUF DASH F15 (FX516PC), но он перестал выдавать видео. На ноутбуке видно что подключил HDMI кабаль + (появляется 2-й монитор в панели). Но видео изображения нет.

Пробовал переустановить Видео драйвера, делал полное обновление драйверов, но не помогло.

- при смене на другой ноутбук изображение есть. (проблема не в экране не в кабеле)
  Но порой удаётся поймать моменты когда есть изображение.(примерно 1 к 10)

Можете подсказать с чем это связано.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! Вопрос задан не по теме сообщества StackOverflow. Вы можете подробнее ознакомится с темами на которые можно задавать вопросы [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: у меня так было, **разъем заедает видимо** (контакт как поймает показывает, а иногда будто пропадает). а еще я читала, что лучше подключать именно ```hdmi``` кабели при выключенном компе/тв, тк они чуствительны и могут сгореть, что и стало с одним портом(по моему, потому что он совсем перестал отвечать)... ну я купила двойник, думала два подключу, а вышло что он ```свич```